# Volume of a solid using the shell method

Tags: calculus

The region bounded by $y= 4x^{2}$, $x=0$, $y=16$, about $y=16$

I used the shell and disk methods, but here I will present my work using shells:

$$2\pi\int_a^b {(16-y)(y^\frac{1}{2})} dy =\frac{8192\pi}{15}$$

with $a=0$ and $b=16$.

I used shells here and solved for my function in terms of $y$ which is $x= \left(\frac{y^\frac{1}{2}}{2}\right)$, but this only shows one half of the graph so I doubled it leaving me with just ${y^\frac{1}{2}}$. Maybe I made my mistake here because the answer should be exactly half of what I got.

If anyone spots my mistake please let me know

Answer (score 1):

The height of the shell at $y$ is $\sqrt{\frac{y}4}=\frac12y^{1/2}$. The region being revolved about the line $y=16$ is bounded by the line $x=0$, so it lies entirely to the right of the $y$-axis, so no doubling is involved: the mirror image region in the second quadrant is not included.

Comment: you are absolutely right, that was my mistake, I had considered both side of the parabola, which was my error. Thank you!

Comment: @ArmanBraca: You’re welcome!